# iOS How to display swf in uiwebview

Tags: flash, ios7

I create a html file in my project. It contains code

```
<p align=center>
   <embed id=17173 
          height=395 
          type=application/x-shockwave-flash 
          width=500 src=http://17173.tv.sohu.com/playercs2008.swf?Flvid=1390648 
          allowScriptAccess=\"always\" 
          allowFullScreen=\"true\">
   </embed> 
</p>
```

But it did not show when I load the html file in `UIWebview`.
How can I resolve this problem.

thanks....

Comment: I would really start looking into html5 videos with a possible flash fallback for those browsers that don't support html5. Flash isn't by default supported by iOS

Answer (score 1):

Flash is not supported on iOS devices. What you're asking simply is not possible.